# How can I speed up this compile code with four variables

Tags: compile

I would like to caculate the following codes with four variables.
When the dimension is 10*10*10*10, the complile time is about 2 seconds.  (just for estimate the time).  When the dimension  the  50*50*50*50, the complile time is about 1200 seconds, (20 mintutes), which is too long time for me, because I need to repeat this calcualtion for many times.

How can I speed up this compile time for  50*50*50*50 dimensions?  Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

```
data = Table[Exp[-((i + j - 50.)/10)^2] Exp[-((i - j)/10)^2], {i, 50}, {j, 50}];
data = Chop[data, 0.00001];
data = data/Sqrt[Sum[(data[[i, j]])^2, {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}]];


c = 2.99792458*10^8;
Δ = 0.16;(*nm*)
λs0 = 1500;
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[2/3], Hue[0]}, #] &)]

CC1[i_, j_, k_, l_, τ_] := 1/2 (2 data[[i, l]]^2 data[[j, k]]^2 + 
 2 data[[i, k]] data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
 2 data[[i, k]]^2 data[[j, l]]^2 + 
 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       i Δ + λs0) + (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       j Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       k Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]])^2 + 
 2 data[[i, j]] data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] data[[k, l]] + 
 2 data[[i, j]] data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] data[[k, l]] + 
 2 data[[i, j]]^2 data[[k, l]]^2 + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       j Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       k Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       i Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       i Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       j Δ + λs0) + (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       k Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]])^2 + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       i Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       k Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       j Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       i Δ + λs0) - (
      2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
       j Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
      l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + k Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
    data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + j Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + k Δ + λs0) + (2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]])^2);

CC2comp = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
Evaluate[
 Sum[CC1[i, j, k, l, t], {i, 10}, {j, 10}, {k, 10}, {l, 10}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListPlot[Table[{i, CC2comp[i*0.001]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .67, ImageSize -> {400, 250}] // AbsoluteTiming


CC2comp = Compile[{{t, _Real}},  Evaluate[
 Sum[CC1[i, j, k, l, t], {i, 50}, {j, 50}, {k, 50}, {l, 50}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListPlot[Table[{i, CC2comp[i*0.001]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {All, All},  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .67,  ImageSize -> {400, 250}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: @Shutao Tang, Many thanks to Shutao Tang for re-editing!   How can I input Δ here? I just copy the code from a Mathematica notebook, and the result is \[CapitalDelta].

Comment: See ***Mathematica Editor-buttons for StackExchange*** for chrome.

Comment: @Shutao Tang, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is slow is due to the `Evaluate` you have placed in the body of `Compile`: this forces the `Sum` to evaluate with a symbolic `t` in the place of `τ`, and use the resulting symbolic formula as the body of `Compile`. This symbolic processing is slow and unnecessary.

My proposal is to make a `Compile`d function of `CC1` and then calling that from the compiled `CC2`:

```
CC1 = Compile[{{data, _Real, 
    2}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}, {l, _Integer}, {\
τ, _Real}}, 
  1/2 (2 data[[i, l]]^2 data[[j, k]]^2 + 
     2 data[[i, k]] data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
     2 data[[i, k]]^2 data[[j, l]]^2 + 
     Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) + (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
            l]] data[[j, k]] + data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]])^2 + 
     2 data[[i, j]] data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] data[[k, l]] + 
     2 data[[i, j]] data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] data[[k, l]] + 
     2 data[[i, j]]^2 data[[k, l]]^2 + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0) + (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
            l]] data[[j, k]] + data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]])^2 + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     2 Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
           l]] data[[j, k]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) (data[[i, k]] data[[j, l]] + 
        data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]]) + 
     Cos[((2 c π)/(-4 - 0.5` Δ + 
             i Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             j Δ + λs0) - (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             k Δ + λs0) + (2 c π)/(-4 - 
             0.5` Δ + 
             l Δ + λs0)) τ] (data[[i, 
            k]] data[[j, l]] + data[[i, j]] data[[k, l]])^2)
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"
  , CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
  ]
```

and

```
CC2comp = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {dat, _Real, 2}},
    Sum[CC1[dat, i, j, k, l, t], {i, 50}, {j, 50}, {k, 50}, {l, 50}]
    ,
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
       True}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.556052, Null}`

You can drop the compilation to C if you don't have a working compiler but for such low-level operations as here, compiling to C should help quite a bit.

Now, the plot takes some time to create, but that's expected since each plot points needs the 50*50*50*50 sum to be evaluated, but it's still much less than waiting for the symbolic sum.

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, CC2comp[i*0.001, data]}, {i, -10, 10, 0.1}], 
  Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .67, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 250}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

An alternative way would be to try to speed of the generation of the symbolic result of the sum. To approach this I would try to vectorize some of the sums if possible, do vector operations, and use `Total` instead of `Sum`, but I don't have time to investigate this right now :/ If I have time later, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Hi Marius Ladegård Meyer, Thank you so much for your good answer!

Comment: I am also looking forward to seeing the AbsoluteTiming results for codes with Total instead of Sum.

Comment: Can the speed be faster if I use Matlab codes instead of Mathematica codes?